# How to save event id from google calendar to google sheets without overwriting formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

This is my first attempt at using scripting in Google Sheets. I'm trying to create a script that will create calendar events based on my data in my spreadsheet. I pulled from an example posted here.

This code will pull the data from my sheet, check if the event exists, if it doesn't it will create the event, if it does it will delete the event and create a new one (i needed to be able to edit the times of an event) this is all based on the event id that is recorded to the sheet upon event creation.

This works great, but when it records the event id the code records all data back to the spreadsheet which then overwrites cells with data instead of the formulas i'm using.

how can I update this code so it only updates the eventID and not everything?

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the exportEvents() function.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export Events",
    functionName : "exportEvents"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "715rn8uj1trqc31e6mepgsnk7k@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);  // First column
    var title = row[13];           // Fourteenth column
    var tstart = new Date(row[2]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[3]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var loc = "1117 w 24th Street, Los Angeles, CA 90007";
    var desc = row[14];
    var id = row[15];              // Sisteenth column == eventId
    // Check if event already exists, delete it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventById(id)
      event.deleteEvent();
      row[15] = '';  // Remove event ID    
      }
    catch (e) {
        // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
      }
      //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
    var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
    row[15] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
    debugger;

// Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
    idrange.setValues(data);
    }

}


function testRange () {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 logger.log(data);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `range` is `range = sheet.getDataRange()` you keep reading and overwriting everything on the sheet. Let's only write the Ids. First, make a smaller array of data, which only has the Id column. Then put it in the spreadsheet where it belongs: in 16th column (was 15 in 0-based index, but 16 in 1-based index).

The following should be placed **after** the for loop, not within it.

```
// Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
var id_data = data.map(function (row) {
  return [row[15]];      // keep only that column
});
sheet.getRange(1, 16, id_data.length, 1).setValues(id_data);  // write it in the sheet
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I'd spent hours searching for the solution, but since I'm still unfamiliar with how everything works I didn't know what to look for. Thank you!