# How to write Google Calendar Events from Sheets AND write EventID back to Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to write events from Google Sheets to Google Calendar. However, I want to modify my code to write the Event ID back to the Google Sheet. This code successfully writes the events. However, I am not sure how to modify it to write the event ID for the created event back to the spreadsheet. Any help is appreciated!

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
    /** Create Marketing Events from Google Spreadsheet **/
  
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("F1").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  
    /** I have grabbed the active sheet, specified the cell in which to find the calendar Id, and lastly, told the CalendarApp which calendar to write events to. **/
  
    var marketingEntries = spreadsheet.getRange("A4:F100").getValues();
  
    /** Now we need to pull in the fields of data that we want to turn into events. **/
  
    for (x=0; x<marketingEntries.length; x++) {
      
      var markEntry = marketingEntries[x];
  
      var title = markEntry[0]
      var date = markEntry[1]
      var descrip = markEntry[2]
      var gues = markEntry[3]
      /** var sendInvites = markEntry[] **/
  
      eventCal.createAllDayEvent(title , new Date(date) , {description: descrip, guests: gues});
    }
  }
```

I have also included a screenshot of the sheet I working to build this out of.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUW8i.png)

I have been looking through other stack overflow posts (like this one: [How to save event id from google calendar to google sheets without overwriting formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935059/how-to-save-event-id-from-google-calendar-to-google-sheets-without-overwriting-f)) and thorugh the Google Developer pages but I am not sure how to write the ID of the event as it is being created or right after it is created, to the spreadsheet in the EventId column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code works to clear my sheet from A5:J and then gets the calendar events and writes them back to my sheet starting in row 9.

```js
//Pull Calendar Events by Calendar ID and Sets the Sheet Name where you want the events to populate.
function getCalendarEvents() {
  var calendarId = 'CALENDAR ID'; // Replace with the ID of the Google Calendar you want to pull events from
  var sheetName = 'SHEET NAME'; // Replace with the name of the sheet where you want to output the events
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rangeStart = sheet.getRange('C3').getValues();
  var rangeEnd = sheet.getRange('F3').getValues();
  var start = new Date(rangeStart);
  var end = new Date(rangeEnd);
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {timeMin: start.toISOString(), timeMax: end.toISOString(), singleEvents: true, orderBy: 'startTime'}).items;
  
  sheet.getRange('A5:J').clearContent(); // Clear existing data in the sheet from row 5 downward, columns A through J
  
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    var title = event.summary || '';
    var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date || '';
      if (start) {
        start = new Date(start).toISOString().slice(0,10);
      }
    var end = event.end.dateTime || event.end.date || '';
    if (end) {
        end = new Date(end).toISOString().slice(0,10);
      }
    var description = event.description || '';
    var guests = event.attendees ? event.attendees.map(function(attendee) { return attendee.email; }).join(', ') : '';
    var color = event.colorId || '';
    var id = event.id || '';
    
    data.push([id, title, start, end, description, guests, color ]);
  }
  
  if (data.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(9, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); // Pushes the calendar data to the sheet starting in row 9
  }
}
```

Then, I created some rows where I could specify whether or not I wanted to create a new calendar event, update an event, or delete an event by checking to see if the word or value of "TRUE" was in the right field. This is what I am calling Calendar Sync:

```js
function syncWithCalendar() {
  var calendarId = 'CALENDAR ID';
  var sheetName = 'SHEET NAME'; // Replace with the name of the sheet where you want to output the events
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange('A5:J').getValues(); // retrieve data starting from row 5
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var event = {
      'id': data[i][0],
      'title': data[i][1],
      'start': new Date(data[i][2]),
      'starttwo': data[i][2],
      'end': new Date(data[i][3]),
      'endtwo': data[i][3],
      'description': data[i][4],
      'guests': data[i][5].split(",").map(function(email) { return email.trim(); }), // split the string into an array of email addresses
      'color': data[i][6],
    };
    var desc = data[i][4];
    var gues = data[i][5];
    var col  = data[i][6];

    if (data[i][7]) { // if update event is true
      var calendarEvent = calendar.getEventById(event.id);
      calendarEvent.setTitle(event.title);
      calendarEvent.setTime(event.start, event.end);
      calendarEvent.setDescription(event.description);
      calendarEvent.setColor(event.color);
        

      // Remove guests not present in the sheet. Not sure this is working???
      var existingGuests = calendarEvent.getGuestList();
      for (var j = 0; j < existingGuests.length; j++) {
        var email = existingGuests[j].getEmail();
        if (event.guests.indexOf(email) === -1) {
          calendarEvent.removeGuest(email);
        }
      }

      // Add guests from the sheet not already present. This definitely works. 
      for (var k = 0; k < event.guests.length; k++) {
        if (existingGuests.map(function(guest) { return guest.getEmail(); }).indexOf(event.guests[k]) === -1) {
          calendarEvent.addGuest(event.guests[k]);
        }
      }

    }
    
    if (data[i][8]) { // if new event is true
      console.log('Creating new event:');
      console.log('Title: ' + event.title);
      console.log('Start: ' + event.start);
      console.log('End: ' + event.end);
      console.log('Description: ' + event.description);
      console.log('Guests: ' + event.guests);
      console.log('Color: ' + event.color);
      var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(event.title, new Date(event.starttwo), new Date(event.endtwo),{
       description: desc,
       guests: gues,
       color: col,
       }); 
    sheet.getRange(i+5, 1).setValue(newEvent.getId()); // write new event ID back to column A
    
    // Now update the new event
    var updatedEvent = {
    'id': newEvent.getId(),
    'title': event.title,
    'start': new Date(event.starttwo),
    'starttwo': event.starttwo,
    'end': new Date(event.endtwo),
    'endtwo': event.endtwo,
    'description': event.description,
    'guests': event.guests,
    'color': event.color,
  };
  var desc = event.description;
  var gues = event.guests;
  var col  = event.color;
  
  var calendarEvent = calendar.getEventById(updatedEvent.id);
  calendarEvent.setTitle(updatedEvent.title);
  calendarEvent.setTime(updatedEvent.start, updatedEvent.end);
  calendarEvent.setDescription(updatedEvent.description);
  calendarEvent.setColor(updatedEvent.color);
  }


    if (data[i][9]) { // if delete event is true
      var calendarEvent = calendar.getEventById(event.id);
      calendarEvent.deleteEvent();
      sheet.getRange(i+5, 1).setValue(''); // clear the event ID in column A
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange('H5:J').clearContent(); // Clear boolean value change operaters
}
```

The worksheet that goes with this code is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9mwwNtmpDcyWmxgkakB1YTiaplbBxYeLQjYC7ds0Fo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will write the event Ids to the sheet.

```
   function createCalendarEvent() {
      /** Create Marketing Events from Google Spreadsheet **/
    
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("F1").getValue();
      var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    
      /** I have grabbed the active sheet, specified the cell in which to find the calendar Id, and lastly, told the CalendarApp which calendar to write events to. **/
    
      var marketingEntries = spreadsheet.getRange("A4:F100").getValues();
    
      /** Now we need to pull in the fields of data that we want to turn into events. **/
    
      var eventIds = [];
      for (x = 0; x < marketingEntries.length; x++) {
    
        var markEntry = marketingEntries[x];
    
        var title = markEntry[0]
        var date = markEntry[1]
        var descrip = markEntry[2]
        var gues = markEntry[3]
        /** var sendInvites = markEntry[] **/
    
        var event = eventCal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date), { description: descrip, guests: gues });
        var eventId = event.getId();
        eventIds.push([eventId]);
      }
    
      spreadsheet.getRange("G4:G100").setValues(eventIds);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to create events on my calendar to create reminders for me each day.  The code saves all of the ids back into the spreadsheet so that I can delete them all at one time if I wish to change them.

GS:

```
function createMyEventsFromList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('MakeEvents');
  const shsr = 3;
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Get StartDate","yyyy/M/d",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var t = r.getResponseText().split('/');
  } else {
    ss.toast("Making Events","Cancelled Operation by User",5)
    return;
  }
  let d = new Date(t[0],Number(t[1]) - 1,t[2]);
  sh.getRange("C1").setValue(d).setNumberFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
  sh.getRange("E1").setValue(d).setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  const vs = sh.getRange(shsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r,i) => {r[9] = i + shsr;return r; }).filter(r => r[0] == true).filter(e => e);
  if (vs && vs.length > 0) {
    ss.toast('Process Running','Creating Events',300)
    vs.forEach(r => {
      let idA = [];
      let title = r[1];
      let hours;
      if (~r[2].toString().indexOf(',')) {
        hours = r[2].toString().split(',').map(e => Number(e));
      } else {
        hours = [r[2]];
      }
      let nots;
      if (~r[3].toString().indexOf(",")) {
        nots = r[3].toString().split(',').map(e => Number(e));
      } else {
        nots = [r[3]];
      }
      let desc = r[4];
      let start = r[5];
      let end = r[6];
      let offA;
      if (r[7] && r[7].toString().length > 0) {
        if (r[7].toString().includes(',')) {
          offA = r[7].toString().split(',').map(e => Number(e));
        } else {
          offA = [r[7]];
        }
      }
      const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("q289qp9augtnshkn70dkibcc54@group.calendar.google.com");
      const tob = { start: start, end: end, offA: offA, desc: desc, tA: [{ title: title, hours: hours, nots: nots }] };
      makeEventArray(tob.start, tob.end, tob.offA).forEach(offset => {
        let dt = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + offset);
        tob.tA.forEach(obj => {
          obj.hours.forEach(h => {
            let st = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), h)
            let et = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), h + 1);
            let event = cal.createEvent(obj.title, st, et);;
            if (event) {
              event.setDescription(tob.desc);
              idA.push(event.getId())
            }
            if (event && obj.nots && obj.nots.length > 0) {
              obj.nots.forEach(m => {
                event.addPopupReminder(m);
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
      sh.getRange(r[9],9,1,3).setValues([[idA.join(', '),r[9],sh.getRange("C1").getDisplayValue()]])
    });
    ss.toast('Process Complete','Creating Events',15);
  }
}
```

The MakeEvent Sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Select | Title | Hours | Notifications | Description | Start | End | Hardcoded Offset Array | Event Ids | Row | Date |
| 3 | Redacted | Redacted | 8 | 15,30 | Redacted |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Redacted | Redacted | 8,22 | 15,30,60,120 | Redacted |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Redacted | test1 | 7 | 15 | Desc 1 | 0 | 2 |  |  | 5 | Redacted |
| 6 | Redacted | test2 | 8,10 | 15,30 | Desc 2 |  |  | 1,3 |  |  | Redacted |
| 7 | Redacted | Redacted | 8 | 15,30 | Redacted | 0 | 29 |  | fplpd01msjq8u8oc7ddlgft6gk@google.com, he1a6jnnod1cjpjo74uuf2acp8@google.com, ne27c9rrmo67n32n4j03sm9r80@google.com, k08i4no4nd74sjf58cj47chvec@google.com, n88bi0voer0gn9mup6ig9vii1o@google.com, p9bgnpfnqbghu0ul2t1dgjlee4@google.com, rbr86mfjkkd6hjoq76vcd1h1g0@google.com, ha0d5bac75kbo4cgbm6roagtu8@google.com, 643n0aqg1jlci15th3mm29ba3s@google.com, 9tau6a348g62u6qnucqverdbq4@google.com, 2c1qhl2f569ei0m0n77967b80s@google.com, 5ksijq0vnl1he4ivrcs5j0vvdc@google.com, 209q8dccvio4517t3heut2oqr0@google.com, ok9b6l0ph7lcr108089f22ju8g@google.com, ldh6b14mt6lpbnu0j7dek85q4c@google.com, krn90t1mc08dorg312pntcv3ag@google.com, drl4on3t2bs0oo907c78l2jh5g@google.com, 17mgsp4itmvlo5tlpel338j73o@google.com, tjpmcbecva0f4g9oucd4vb630k@google.com, 7qqvt3p1u3gr3gth5beu9jdhig@google.com, rb92fmc1i22r70s4vkufjet4qk@google.com, 9v7olr82v44as7dmi18konh07g@google.com, kkg8hfu9cfkefhhfrgtsck5f0k@google.com, rj3o04h2ora24242u8isr8o2e4@google.com, u1lbaaismj479u9dbtastpp21c@google.com, ivohq60th9qh53rutidp0o9edo@google.com, tffhku1nto3p36prob82o4l3ug@google.com, 2ofrf5tgo290o0a9tghb3pdqoc@google.com, rqac54d48rb96v8vl0d3c4cc6k@google.com, hg56pifielg6rusfhp6eh48v54@google.com | 7 | Redacted |
| 8 | Redacted | Redacted | 8,22 | 15,30,60,120 | Redacted | 0 | 29 |  | b56ur2kj6a8fotqjsjprfalcp0@google.com, ns6bmdrunejppcr0gvu3iv7qis@google.com, 0r985nnsjehtrqu6q80viftldk@google.com, q8u8gp5o3e84s7qof01b25ecp8@google.com, 5pbvh8oalq47kit8v1qd44d1qc@google.com, kbbigivrsgvrghlohdp0v6771k@google.com, o5kc2c2ipdbaeqpbpfjmllsn60@google.com, 7j49bjov10btju7abvh5jtrtjc@google.com, 0balanbep83s4pbt372vscn5n4@google.com, ghrs2lj3kanabr17n42cj21t6k@google.com, bjgqu6mqvhnaochtdhds0egshg@google.com, ddrjdoccsslepm6m2635vsa4p8@google.com, 76qdjphg6naalffd17tiqit0t4@google.com, 7143gmcu5iq4bllbvp3fmm9hes@google.com, 71l1vrj0grc7juksavqpmb5flg@google.com, d8a11vsnvadgcm70qfkfjov9d0@google.com, nlfictn86nqnr2f1vqssl4u6e0@google.com, e561mvg1jr2fut05p2ndhj7vjs@google.com, kbqqn369om0e76upjgojlf6poo@google.com, bmtcekg8f6m68dk9t52g89eu70@google.com, eqsjm508j8icl2gqju97lpqqn4@google.com, dpth7r332v01adegksospsquo4@google.com, m82hjsnomufjc5vv10gq16s08k@google.com, crk3afc9iciuo1arcamg3ii0po@google.com, krivtti002maeh63emdkuuaqrk@google.com, caqospiob7atfi6mqbuevf109c@google.com, ke14dd03d83gunhs9hb8uj8fn4@google.com, 5d0sga218bn2qls7orm2rpqvik@google.com, g98kgvtj8s8rl4j1qphvpt2k00@google.com, tvpv3ct29qenk0lldlusqt68q8@google.com, brth61o239250atc2gc6kqc5ps@google.com, 3c297884hc7orctkm3tlrks828@google.com, 0er30nfeubqj6qhb722beisbo8@google.com, v4niue8looag17catjc9jt9m5s@google.com, osnmhhu7vkred2u4rpu9q8b8n0@google.com, a5sq21u0uqrc2r2opbf1pt7jdg@google.com, t0h9jv6hjvnojq41n65vu3qlck@google.com, calcm8vat8jji22j56ousb9de4@google.com, 0l7urf2pjceankq87h1t18ijuo@google.com, 74cm238dnbgh2odi0qm40fpqlo@google.com, m1pl2h0f2bns309scc9nmuaek0@google.com, icfrh8696fo3a3f8o2jr60okmc@google.com, rekco0guuoqg62g3irmihgo1d8@google.com, efufrcb9kgkgvt7e7glq8nupdg@google.com, ifbvce6t0k0cbovpmjp22ulvvc@google.com, ou0fanvi4h3m8j4fsb39jhejpg@google.com, mucqrvun5phquh3lvkf536om90@google.com, 5iro5f29tq1uq9n98am6v3crmg@google.com, 1ffk842ctp46ceq30p6ehd15r8@google.com, mlc9ek92a2fue7frclv33p5uvo@google.com, 0nm36gaa37pvdseqdo5icqtcpg@google.com, b0h04haev9davn48dupkq3qbsk@google.com, 7hnej72l7gmhvilckqqb0t723k@google.com, eqla85fl1pot42ta7mejvghde8@google.com, goubehs4b69h2o4qispnihsohc@google.com, 5i24hmkqhon1uqmjlkpuu658l8@google.com, mejutaqafp8ecvj6df6r6or6q8@google.com, bcph5va0t2fdd987raed05vj5k@google.com, s08bjl4lgjbvasca8fnnp3j0f0@google.com, 7vnljn9sdg42hvgl294o4b0jqs@google.com | 8 | Redacted |
| 9 | Redacted | Redacted | 8 | 15,30 | Redacted | 0 | 30 |  | c9avdpkkhb3vtn0s5u4cgcc5lc@google.com, ivs2nsf7idt2c8ksgi3bgt2dg8@google.com, ur97hqhj9gbbfceprvoia3jhgg@google.com, h46jvji38nuqqpdhg5bc1in3l0@google.com, 0pmt3ffs2qvp50a0lb47tpko9o@google.com, i4h5b502gf20b6260g73e92c2g@google.com, ccf0jgneeppal7fjf4eaabcivo@google.com, 2p731umv2cgs6l2qaj8j328be4@google.com, ico8f9giq4r5a8efv2v4gk1cjc@google.com, vhofrgds2c05h3bj3c57oc87ss@google.com, houi4g709trugmv29dpads2v00@google.com, 2f13kno8otd4cij4uj66le9urk@google.com, 14sql9s26t6atpqbbmhdmtud1o@google.com, a03pd19lbcf7inmc4khlvsli00@google.com, 30c6g8tu807avvkgai4on463cs@google.com, tbjc8l01e6lvla44726tgj3a8g@google.com, fc498apj983pehkja67p7j624s@google.com, mh4dg8c4pilh1o36gcdd3m5vps@google.com, jpkcn6on8ha86jr9qg4neg3tm0@google.com, 128f1l8d4r984ovc0clqfhekd0@google.com, pc5srhrsu484qvv68q7jcjenho@google.com, j53a35rkfbaume69c8rhn1hkok@google.com, 370k6scs2spnosmufjlgtv8iqg@google.com, 0kl12on86qjepq7bs7aqshg018@google.com, 7molrl3c3j4cr7l7bls0tosrdc@google.com, 8f8384sa39j1frs93vmup2j53s@google.com, 3ipn4iludhec83nrco67glbtcc@google.com, gb4v5tvnm2ld9pg85i07kibtak@google.com, qa3furfdja9g56ks4lbdfarg00@google.com, ef2jnttf8igu7fgjt3lrma1bko@google.com, fur9re4dcjemk34ap8f2a34au0@google.com | 9 | Redacted |
| 10 | Redacted | Redacted | 8,22 | 15,30,60,120 | Redacted | 0 | 30 |  | f9mpbqat93nct40hiehkkd4k5o@google.com, 2uha9k3n8rfi1pfpgpvhl7o25g@google.com, 59ariffugd7n51sf33865g3v0c@google.com, eb3pl4o5i2v7bpeucf0mr2qvjs@google.com, 553jkci2a8sgqjg35d9fr37s3c@google.com, obugai9jskkugnplj27d99cnt0@google.com, 98drq4pra426csv8n2s7gda828@google.com, u56sj28qvll2af08m8pf2h3l98@google.com, k9dh3j48d7um5hjmq3npt62nm8@google.com, 28nh4qavi9h5p5olhmnbauu5s0@google.com, csq7piglqvoukplt492n7tl0dc@google.com, a63bok9erkgdvmc6h90a2ch4ks@google.com, 9e0vu5hk5q589q1at3fndumn84@google.com, jahi7mr91v2g23hl8gfcqbpfr4@google.com, ig8tqeqajaeuv1qbq2leu8vs8o@google.com, 18s6cgtnm0os7gnccp8il070dk@google.com, 1jd5vfmj0u9v3t18cb13h7622o@google.com, s6q0o00kqhu5uqjvijf24ecu00@google.com, mcuckl5g7m9gdfme2m1fugbmks@google.com, dbkjb2gs934ol971t7pg7gjqn4@google.com, 0r69aoqg1bqdt8unf3k8l7q4lo@google.com, 7pbq42lbl6rtgnsk6fpbe5le7o@google.com, h2vtidoba369a0e5239mfqn6q4@google.com, 7oc8huhclbv913kqaa785b2ft0@google.com, 0aq9nsh2ncfdt2d0fn18aqndss@google.com, 054qi5vvg4j1fv0sd2rpq3nifs@google.com, gafdttqo3hcekm1t21iivr0pgg@google.com, anmfhbo0ssa28pefncqogsao5s@google.com, mpv8ia8plql9koq0ogbprhrupo@google.com, 497oroau5luscinikn3r1kmegg@google.com, h93gt6jvor49oq7gd1l4um6jno@google.com, v95v5a9glh2hidf2dun7f2tqug@google.com, scinrklj3k0talcaubdfv37624@google.com, 61uo7vqrt20bd29d6d2smon4u4@google.com, dh79us34tjg1hevl52iregeifc@google.com, olo11ou889abphucc3pet6m078@google.com, vff7ej53qdu0hvrhk5ch1hurp8@google.com, kk7j9o9091trh53hdaivbunag0@google.com, 459mk0cfo1cb8a7ucpcu2pis6k@google.com, o6ht9lt9m486crts2m6lfq6s2s@google.com, o4gi5gp5qkhlsgufkvghkufqqo@google.com, jqa0aj1issn58jcc4h4lphb3hg@google.com, 060lti173vb1s0qflv6n9fgn40@google.com, 2u7nklbpnpn1r8n47lkuqdrvl0@google.com, lrfv1g5p6f3vf0obsb2klq1pmc@google.com, prhnjva4474l22nb6dd0rtbhb4@google.com, dv3a1iht9afbnkc4b0qrqb3pm4@google.com, 21cl8k688uuutbjfe0s1i4k0cs@google.com, n0522bnme1o0ig75q7j5fal7g0@google.com, d68n4ijvu1hbqfu10o5t1qo4g0@google.com, 55boqrnd5mlrsceqkbs52bbbj0@google.com, ir68krvo9au5lqtqrdrls3o8pc@google.com, urkjfsubpljm4jke1qf5vg3qpg@google.com, d1vvii1rnfnc7lse3lnaqt0oig@google.com, b9rjsot7mbom5huflq1sqmksd4@google.com, brsaev7vmqbcgkv8eng6fjkbcg@google.com, l630kr7vkmvl646bl4b4d03474@google.com, gdkjv2qdr0e0pmbvvo34nsr3o8@google.com, ov9chb6mog5uiq8t1dljbtthao@google.com, pmc5a35ekv23mi9jos1hikk37g@google.com, 5qnav3b87b6hm9t311ujcmbti0@google.com, p828lpegae2qun3103enbbpbr0@google.com | 10 | Redacted |
| 11 | Redacted | Redacted | 20 | 15,30,60 | Redacted | 0 | 12 |  | h7p5qdcgmlu9f8ol00aoo4lka0@google.com, tq7l4nnn0nkn3ei5ihtnn95kak@google.com, auo5ld7bdvqg2g0h9bq8gra9dg@google.com, tl0qmj18hkpvi7fdhq9head760@google.com, ad2qk7gic89cu1i2tvgj9a14ks@google.com, 4muchrl8jjq9as1ljqkfnr3bg8@google.com, njbmgi9g77nfogvrn48a93k818@google.com, rquiachgbsvi9ralnhqq72hno0@google.com, o671hr58jrkt4db1r95gajc6r4@google.com, vk7m2hjctskm9dcndp08fmuouk@google.com, k4nff2ot1cqjeb8rjdrugft068@google.com, f4h90f39ekcffmdsaq7qsvf4g0@google.com, mgdngii5vg0qqg31rlc2ge6lag@google.com | 11 | Redacted |
| 12 | Redacted | Redacted | 20 | 15,30,60 | Redacted | 0 | 12 |  | ppenoctpdm5fbko36p2jhpb34g@google.com, p34p93e8qt67i2g274hsqboepk@google.com, 8a4rp06a88ufe38n0b13qq3dc4@google.com, 69qnsk1a7h469qk7bdmotrekg4@google.com, a75gm0da6qdk3f479ornjdve9o@google.com, d7fa8f20knkbtnhk7uck0ptlk0@google.com, 9k5se27g5vivlekh2lgfjopm5k@google.com, pe3u022anpo2jqmvohpbn04tm0@google.com, jp16cpn74jvkiertvj4qscib90@google.com, 4h1374ub044budg5f9sosgi9qk@google.com, 7v7365h6j665nm4mtcql5c6904@google.com, ufprnkjnn4mp3l5u74sipuu39s@google.com, 3vsrjjlgcdq71udqaiedmvnpf8@google.com | 12 | Redacted |
| 13 | Redacted | Redacted | 8,22 | 15,30 |  | 0 | 21 |  | fgav9isv082te4abut8qfc349g@google.com, 3bft0opk1lvk0ad386f93mjpk0@google.com, jmmnfo9c8h1o0em34p88frnn18@google.com, cga01ig5b1lgfsseig43209sso@google.com, do4gog21hhpf3n83vrq63fsgr8@google.com, f747s9nsh2fgnsg2j6nbfu757k@google.com, g30a0j7fdm4rllbm90l3284ho4@google.com, 394q3c8m6mf96fil73v9avi8vk@google.com, c6ke3mijms46v9jojjch8ebul8@google.com, 60nvo5c97tjl2hfss38t1vpkto@google.com, mkk1rpojiop0kuockfio777ugo@google.com, k39l7s7f2j1g49u9ah849ddbec@google.com, 6lpu2r3c51reitd3su3tg7kkfk@google.com, ejoe9gcrd6bf6okj5lkf81rl3g@google.com, 01eq0hce8f2jmg62ols5u8b3vk@google.com, hj5p281uas7ijh75nt15tnfie0@google.com, b3qesv96ufhjjn8v9k4rr3g9sg@google.com, 06r6ph13mk90packhnvkkkt2ss@google.com, qetoke03ms8kqmnjfv19ummjdo@google.com, 6b2bjumeetoufkctf4mn2ad37g@google.com, 55nba948kp43gtg5825e3kvkno@google.com, 15ard2lbbcikdm7scvn06ktveo@google.com, 6t9l5i8166osbu05jg787b8728@google.com, metja8kuk5chhi7oa6lq3d2o4o@google.com, cdr0fa7pe3brrvu17kahqbn5k4@google.com, fdsb2pbfvhm03qtatqevklhnrc@google.com, i2ja3c81chicqjk173q4hmh5ek@google.com, oi6phcq8cuqlpasp25loe5120c@google.com, 84lp9gdato63odbs8t9mpvinik@google.com, t97o4a544qrn4v3amqtmq1d0bs@google.com, um9grubbu7quu8tl7r4veivvro@google.com, 6fc12dlqaletjs8lidr2p0ru9g@google.com, fhomu9kvs07tgp45m31uqfd9lo@google.com, ion4bl68rkfc7bqpfmquqbhlcc@google.com, qcj54arjr6j6adk43cpim1f7uk@google.com, ncq2lq77t8ln8cs0ckjto3tc4g@google.com, pbdjv9bgrd3q4hhdde9fi8dsag@google.com, k9p3vv6lh3djhgf71439rf4ibo@google.com, uh245ce85eeq1ifcdlvrfheu3c@google.com, sgggdplhaegktkfmabk8oh2ooc@google.com, 75iesjp2mqu0opjh1e0jc3inoo@google.com, qm9nvavo8gacj2409ssbmr2frk@google.com, j689hkhkvvpe7gnkkgke3cjjes@google.com, 01149pgverl97ge0jrvtmvgmmo@google.com | 13 | Redacted |
| 14 | Redacted | Redacted | 8,22 | 15,30 |  | 0 | 29 |  | rsr3ppeo8g2v7sufsqnaqsut58@google.com, meco7m871414pa0sqi0rhfr060@google.com, tkd4l1cnt8b1lirqjcl9foem6k@google.com, evld3efkoqlievqenmf24nmg1k@google.com, un823ao40duo33gpp90vs64l5k@google.com, omspev5cs004idp8lb1c6q9ras@google.com, vkoibrvcdu8dmqp48jsobh4k8c@google.com, d6ce5u4lk06t34cmilo5b2ourg@google.com, j0e02ncrs6b6fsmp4eemfa6hso@google.com, 1bb06hhmi0e78ffmht2v78lu4o@google.com, 7h4355h3st22p62rga17bfc1c8@google.com, q38a62lu6hdqqnua2mgr3up69c@google.com, 4mgf98qg184l4pq0103a0t0b2s@google.com, h2thtvbr8j5gr3rgf1cfiaiauk@google.com, pfdk99phf6k981dcu0q6q1d54s@google.com, fb1cn5aruotkg5ghsvq5k1mh7g@google.com, kv34p8uaj8mpvg4e1cmqfna4g4@google.com, lgbirl7pfg36q0h2a8uqppkao8@google.com, f0grrb3m51ep39elcjb5nac9s4@google.com, a29gp0g6utqpc6oh5sm11ijir0@google.com, 7q01os75ehsg7gspfhdn91vnb0@google.com, rvc371fu6cpvf8dvrhhocnm25k@google.com, ljel4caeg3a2keka2ltmdr0a4s@google.com, vsq638mg0fqqdjcokr1bgbf8e8@google.com, rbprungoks9137jok9703hub64@google.com, lj0h3bbt8iom5td37dc34go6rc@google.com, idee7k7advgebaqsjm5iut55b0@google.com, ivu646i85mit55l7kc84a5gvdk@google.com, k7vvhsej7m4i3idr189otlogmg@google.com, bmh0fej5hcg9ddvkhser8cu8ms@google.com, 4ef7su22ldnkat5u0uneo9i7hk@google.com, 5fc1lv17mm07u71pmo73bt2j5c@google.com, bqak9rd9fja42lv8g2mj236t38@google.com, 3dvpii2kbel9bi3t7j9dolb29c@google.com, q26v85cd8kn881onf9i68qok60@google.com, 8fscd4cuodpid53fkv11nd6p0c@google.com, 20q8pd157jib03dka37qdnif60@google.com, injiusu5g3nts2gqj7ikc1ddvg@google.com, ctum4t8mikokdpe163mjvikj38@google.com, cujf2dnii8m514f681urhe2keo@google.com, vnnv9hkn6e102f84f1g1s94nck@google.com, meinnb0h0m82di51smpaa9a7ks@google.com, b2rkanatjsa5qe0ig2cuo345d8@google.com, loqva02or96rrcie2le70p4rg4@google.com, l2hts7f69912avs1fl43lp1sdo@google.com, 3p63iidurl4u0j3n97gaenjbq0@google.com, 6su7h9udnm3bk7cf2t4lvot3ic@google.com, nlo537ncs4vk99njonv8dapjco@google.com, 2u9m7r5f5hkhnlt0jblf9q4lbs@google.com, 21strostmt49k2ndolfs89j270@google.com, ssve77l73m8q0ueir2fmam85uk@google.com, sslknlmbtqg6gbfo1fogjsshc4@google.com, lk9vkhec2thtvbh67nk4t0pn3s@google.com, 92gei7nfjube6ljl80kt8ops94@google.com, 2cf5gk3qlfijtvdjrt3rmrgkrg@google.com, luajh2e5089lq1vk7fllbhq9as@google.com, pn1ho09tsvekmca810s23udn7g@google.com, 5b157jupbqneq9dcng4naogckg@google.com, dj3k0tsb6s81s0ndp6ladpjnk8@google.com, 4onjn4ktmk560urs5g3aqi0et4@google.com | 14 | Redacted |
| 15 | Redacted | Redacted | 8,22 | 15,30 |  | 0 | 30 |  | 4mp9m7d3j9s5ftmunjlotqpbls@google.com, be2go98rai8kn26u764ochrgu4@google.com, ehj2rkp45q6gshuktkfjknkog0@google.com, fs82f0uej4n6lto4p0fdlqnjm0@google.com, 3a2jk3ffhu2f03l6js70hfcmpo@google.com, j3ukcf8h81ltmbptve0hdid3ls@google.com, 2v5boitoidotae0a5lbbnfep9c@google.com, i67c5k38r6aqe857qvo7d3pjjk@google.com, qur18m187pcginkvhnh6f6gmmc@google.com, hf963ra3avp16l18kmrchcvrrg@google.com, bcp775cb4c7ulbr0tfoaeq43o0@google.com, itocg2r194vaqvpjrhgs4jl1bc@google.com, dimcgsk4366so1n90tahmrfl1s@google.com, cjnrh7djlm3jsmvg1r6ulcvmdg@google.com, lkmn4n4rn598tfoeci15s9ete0@google.com, lqrelkdpq2bktattbji6m5e08g@google.com, u5bkaaa6d792fmfku7c4mhiahg@google.com, ugirattu0bld8rou8th9efg04g@google.com, n4fjddhc0ube0fpml8rcdtl9t4@google.com, 0968r25jga33hvj0bsu2p26iic@google.com, e6jmd5f7mi84g04td6gb4ab2oc@google.com, 04oka6hhtdvhofjlt65ljo51t8@google.com, e1skm1o1pb5dn6kan9i4hncgfc@google.com, 2jemfjgadaiafi1osvc8qfvf98@google.com, 1og9osli3plhvnjutfl5fsj48g@google.com, mfnf169brf4hnfm26i2sl8qk88@google.com, gh2lv15vrt4qqr5ij8rc379cuo@google.com, rivko6gabhsfnk9ggb5ajd2eco@google.com, ivmf2gt78ff9ivem7815befj7g@google.com, cke6t8usrqstbep3n2s4ru0se8@google.com, ps7fkg1ssufjprhqbemuiathg0@google.com, 4n2n47octlvj9gnpkrajvsmk5g@google.com, fi1huq92st2hvoqnj773882cps@google.com, rfbrdj7l11vjghtjt23ho3mn30@google.com, 5c63ruan9912lno1nq4e5ngdfc@google.com, g0jl84lnjdtia6vaqrqp8vln7g@google.com, u99vmfodoemi8ptbc1l0sdovjg@google.com, 93antph5psgsr352ag7rmt6ves@google.com, ir5pvk3trbsktm3928lv980kj8@google.com, i6lc0vrje2el5au05r1qpeodok@google.com, mbeqaffknatmna3mdpiufuogng@google.com, ic8i9adrod37mcfetp9apug2gg@google.com, 0edt1n0i5lq4l3edv14gqvf6c0@google.com, 0344hods26mvvg0rdpm2t66e00@google.com, 3ifq4euttscvq5hm51kfcb4qog@google.com, o4hi047ckg388rph3qrbm1u8js@google.com, n3qdepe6837ltotpfhfeeflft4@google.com, dbdmafhol51n7j0hamb23rvvbc@google.com, 3684q6avinrt3up6oh2vq1nsb8@google.com, qhmcf72hknr6i3g7rqk0sahqok@google.com, h38bom8m46cnkpblj744l2skik@google.com, hgsqkr8lslcq6quj7dopu01pts@google.com, v6e8uf5iofqukdhar605v1ev6g@google.com, aiakujiu1bp0k2ieaogmv4cqvk@google.com, 29albo9ikn485og3abiq8h0sg0@google.com, l34c3du1mqa8haj953aubgl55c@google.com, rn8ppjpv7fea9r7c7ctggfgjf4@google.com, 96bum9ntnsts4tdur57amj4id0@google.com, rvvldnbueklfqp7ef5p4hhbcl4@google.com, 981s1h2q74rmdmsqu7d20g4gcc@google.com, 2bmmv791pboq07nnquoa20uc84@google.com, pr0ilpv8s9s782op8923ocd8dg@google.com | 15 | Redacted |

GS:

```
function deleteEventsFromList() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("q289qp9augtnshkn70dkibcc54@group.calendar.google.com");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('MakeEvents');
  const shsr = 3;
  const vs = sh.getRange(shsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r,i) => {r[9] = i + shsr;return r; }).filter(r => r[0] == true).filter(e => e);
  ss.toast('Process Running','Deleeting Events',180)
  vs.forEach(r => {
    r[8].toString().split(', ').forEach(id => {
      cal.getEventById(id).deleteEvent();
    });
    sh.getRange(r[9],9,1,2).clearContent();
  });
  ss.toast('Process Complete','Deleeting Events');
}
```